# "message": "Unexpected parameter ''",Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.PipelineValidationException, Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-pipelines

I started to get an API error despite the fact it worked great until yesterday .

**This is my API :**

[image]

**and my pipeline didn't change:**

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS 10.14'
parameters:
  - name: Folderpath
    type: string
    displayName: 'configure path'
```

**and in Azure DevOps pipeline I get :**

[image]

And now it worked great again.

Comment: Please consider cleaning up the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an event impacting Azure DevOps service yesterday. This might cause the unstability of the service. The issue is now fully mitigated. I tested above rest api, it now works fine.

See [Azure DevOps Status history](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history) for more information.